# Pausing a Workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

Lets say I have a sample workflow that does the following:

1. Receive something
2. Run long activity1 (no user input)
3. Run long activity2 (no user input)
4. Send something

Usually activity2 should run automatically after activity1 is finished, but I would like to prevent the execution of activity2 until the workflow gets the go ahead from a user. While activity1 is running, I want to be able to tell the workflow to pause after it is done activity1 and continue with activity2 when told.

I guess I need a flag that the workflow can check before it run activity2 but how can I update this flag while activity1 is running?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create some kind of blocking activity, either using a bookmark or a WCF request and execute that before activity2 starts. That way you can tell it to resume. You can nest it in an If activity of you only want to wait if a certain condition has not been met.